# Array to string conversion - Variable function name calling

Tags: php, oop

I need to call some functions inside a class; based on variables, something like this:

```
$x->$y();
```

But, I found a strange behavior, consider the following sample code:

```
$arr = array(

    "some_index" => "func_name"
);


$str = "func_name";

class some_class {

    public function func_name() {

        echo "It works in class!";
    }
}

$some_obj = new some_class();

$some_obj->$arr['some_index']();
$some_obj->$str();
```

Now the line

```
$some_obj->$arr['some_index']();
```

gives the errors:

> Array to string conversion in ...
>   Undefined property: some_class::$Array in ...
>   Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in...

But, the line

```
$some_obj->$str();
```

works perfectly.

Also, both the lines will work, if the function is not defined inside a class.

Anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: `$some_obj->{$arr['some_index']}();`

Comment: yeah, that works...do you know the reason for the error ? It used to work in previous versions of PHP

Comment: from "In order to use variable variables* ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: When you say _previous version_, do not forget to add the current version you're using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call it this way:

```
$some_obj->{$arr['some_index']}();
```

[here's a living example](http://www.phpwin.org/s/LmwgEm)